# Eclipse desync files

Tags: sync, file-management, svn, eclipse

Eclipse get desync with the files on the repository I'm working, is there anyway I can set it up so that it refresh automaticaly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting:

```
Preference > General > Workspace > 'Refresh automatically'
```

should help, according to my [old answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323473/j2ee-eclipse-file-uploading-project-requires-refresh-on-package-explorer-before-s/323507#323507)